# What will be/how do I estimate US household income in 2020?

Tags: time-series, prediction

I would like to know what US household income will be in 2020 by age group (eg. 15-34,35-44,45-54,65+). The US Census provides a historical Excel sheet (http://www.census.gov/hhes/www/income/data/historical/household/2010/H10AR_2010.xls) that breaks down this data over the last few decades but of course stops at the year 2010.

I've searched the web wide and far and can't seem to find projections of any kind. Is there a way I can calculate the 2020 figures myself (obviously resulting in a very rough estimate) or is there a projection somewhere out there? Thanks!

Comment: Most likely, you're going to need to do some sort of time series forecasting based on a model. How far back does the time series go?

Comment: Statistical projections into the future are often based on simple-minded assumptions, such as: the trend seen in the past will continue in the future.  Such assumptions are often, even typically, wrong.  For example, the rate of inflation may change, or we may have an unexpected (or expected) financial crisis.  So, think long and hard about how you make projections into the future.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to how much household income is "not enough".

But seriously: There are a number of firms that do these projections: STI (PopStats) and AGS, just to name two we currently purchase (actually we purchase 5 year, but there are other forecasts available).

If you want to do it yourself, heed Joel W's words. In the current very uncertain economic environment, there is a lot of uncertainty. If I had to, I'd take the rate of inflation out (available at the BLS site) and forecast the real value, probably using Holt's exponential smoothing. But if this is the input to a planning exercise, be sure you don't take such a forecast seriously -- good planning is robust enough to survive bad forecasts.

Comment: Even large and fancy firms that do projections often (always?) use simplistic approaches, never (almost never?) including drastic deviations from the past.  (This statement is based on my experience.  I'm sure others will correct me if I'm wrong about this.)  But the future sometimes does bring us unexpected deviations from the past.  So, look long and hard at the assumptions made by your model, whether you do it yourself or buy a service from a fancy consulting service.  And heed zbicyclist's wise observation, "good planning is robust enough to survive bad forecasts."